# How to solve this feed validator error

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my feed's validation and why does it have a weird url in it.
You can see the validation error here:
http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameflik.com%2Ffeed%2F#l22

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's pretty clear. Your feed finishes with `</rss>`, which means there should be no content after this (except maybe a `\n`).

Get rid of everything after `</rss>` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how do I do that?